# Two sub query with one common column

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2012

I change the original question to be more specific.

I have two parameters that I want to get as output after running this query.
The two parameters requires different criteria.

So to do that I built this kind of query:

```
SELECT m.count, ytd.count 
FROM ( 
   SELECT COUNT( id ) count 
   FROM table 
   WHERE date BETWEEN BETWEEN '2010-06-01' AND '2010-06-30'
) m, (SELECT COUNT( id )count 
      FROM table 
      WHERE date BETWEEN BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-06-30'
) ytd
```

This kind of query returns the count and work well.
but now i want to dig a little bit more in and to see those two parameter by dep.

Now i get the total :

```
Param1  Param2
  39      85
```

I wish to get this table :

```
Dep Param1 Param2
  1    5      7
  2    34     78
```

and so on..

Hope that now its more clear.

Thanks!

Comment: Add some sample table data and expected result, and it will be much easier to assist you!

Comment: You can still add some rows of sample data, and manually create the expected result.

Comment: How can i add here a table ? Sorry for noobing a round :\

Comment: Write data in proper columns, mark the rows and press the `{ }` button.

Comment: First try to modify your question and add your table structure, or the query used to create the table

Comment: I figure it out. If someone in the future will be interested..I add to each sub query the dep column and made join between the two virtual tables and connect them On m.dep=ytb.dep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    SELECT m.dep, m.count, ytd.count 
    FROM ( 
          SELECT COUNT( id ) count, Dep 
          FROM table 
          WHERE date BETWEEN BETWEEN '2010-06-01' AND '2010-06-30'
          group by dep
    ) m, 

Join

(   SELECT COUNT( id )count, dep 
          FROM table 
          WHERE date BETWEEN BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-06-30'
          group by dep
    ) ytd

ON ytb.dep=m.dep
```

Thanks for the help